# How to disable Unity code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am trying to code normally in Visual Studio but it says I have to do it in Unity how do I disable this? It says "Attach to Unity" when I try to run it.

I tried going to Unity and switching the preferred things but it didn't do anything and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to check Unity manual available at https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

For example, following topics:

> **Attach your code editor to the Unity Player**

> To attach your code editor
> to the Unity Player, in your code editor, select the IP address (or
> machine name) and port of your Player. For an example of where to find
> this in Visual Studio, see Attach Visual Studio to the Unity Editor.
>
> Note: Your code editor will show all instances of Unity that are
> available to debug. Make sure you attach the code editor to the
> correct instance of the Unity Player, and not to the Unity Editor if
> both are running.
>
> When you have attached the debugger, you can begin debugging normally.
> For instructions on how to attach the Unity Player to your specific
> code editor, see Code editor external documentation. For an example of
> how to attach a Unity Player that runs on a mobile device to Visual
> Studio, see Debug Android and iOS devices with Visual Studio.

and

> **Attach Visual Studio to the Unity Editor**
>
> To attach the Unity Editor to your Visual Studio script, open Visual
> Studio, go to Debug > Attach Unity Debugger and select the instance of
> the Unity Editor you would like to debug.
>
> In the following example image, there is one instance of Unity running
> in the Editor and one instance of Unity running as an Android Player